# Entity Framework does not save related object by foreign key

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework

I got a small application that has multiple entities, running EF on a SQLite database.

One of them as a relation, defined by a foreign key - which i have defined in my DbContext's `OnModelCreating` like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasOptional(entity => entity.Bar)
            .WithRequired(entity => entity.Foo);
```

I've tried to add the `Foo_Id` to `Bar`, and i've tried to add `Bar_Id` to Foo.
Whatever i try to do, EntityFramework is not saving the reference:

```
INSERT INTO [Bar]([Id], [PropertyA], [PropertyB], [PropertyC], [PropertyD])
 VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4);
-- @p0: '12' (Type = Int64)
-- @p1: '3' (Type = Int32)
-- @p2: '2' (Type = Int32)
-- @p3: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- @p4: '4' (Type = Int32)
```

(Where PropertyA-PropertyD are the regular properties of that entity, none of them is FooId)

Same applies when i add it to Foo - it just isn't inserted into the database. My Foreign key always fails. When i remove the foreign key and allow null values, the `Bar` entity is created, but - as it is not defined by the insert query above - the `Foo_Id` is of course null.

Creating and inserting the entity is like:

```
var foo = _context.Set<Foo>.Create();
foo.Bar = new Bar
{
    Foo = foo,
    PropertyA = 1,
    PropertyB = 2,
    PropertyC = 3,
    PropertyD = 4,
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Note: The `Foo` Entity has multiple other references, to other entities, they all do save fine.

What am i missing?

---

Edit:

The definitions of Bar is:

```
<EntityType Name="Bars">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="PropertyA" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="PropertyB" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="PropertyC" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="PropertyD" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="Foo_Id" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
  </EntityType>
```

and Foo is:

```
<EntityType Name="Foos">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
    /* some properties */
  </EntityType>
```

With the association of:

```
<Association Name="FooBar">
    <End Role="Foo" Type="SQLServerModels.Store.Foos" Multiplicity="0..1" />
    <End Role="Bar" Type="SQLServerModels.Store.Bars" Multiplicity="*" />
    <ReferentialConstraint>
      <Principal Role="Foo">
        <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
      </Principal>
      <Dependent Role="Bar">
        <PropertyRef Name="Foo_Id" />
      </Dependent>
    </ReferentialConstraint>
  </Association>
```

Edit: Just found out that it works when using this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>()
                .HasRequired(entity => entity.Foo)
                .WithOptional(entity => entity.Bar)
                .Map
                (
                    a => a.MapKey("Foo_Id")
                );
```

Without the Mapping, it does not save. Why do i need this on this specific entity, and not on all others? Which pitfalls could lead to this?

Comment: Please post the definitions of Foo and Bar.

Comment: The definition in my edmx? Sure, i can update my post.

Comment: Why do you have both a fluent mapping and an edmx?  That’s not normal and may be the cause of your troubles.

Comment: answer your own your own question rather than editing and appending the answer to the bottom of your question.